# MVC Repository Pattern - when to use AutoMapper?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-4

We used Telerik ORM to generate our domain models and have these in a class library that is called the DAL. Then we have our UI project which is a MVC 4 web application. In this, we have repositories and models. The models here are the viewmodels, specifically to display data on the views.

Now my questions are:

1. Should the repository directly return back the viewmodel?
2. Should the viewmodel be converted to an entity?
3. What's overhead in using automapper? Where should it be used?

If we do not convert to the viewmodel in the repository using automapper, we might have different calls to the db to populate each part of the object. A viewmodel for a page might have list of contacts, and a selected contact. The selected contact will be populated with one call to the repository and the list of contacts will be populated with another call. Also if the mapper is at the repository level, wouldn't it be better to remove all the 'extra fields' like gender if we're only interested in 'name and id'?

I have heard that the repository should not return view models because viewmodels are specific to UI and should not be involved in the data layer. Is this true?

Answer (score 2):

Your repository should return plain domain objects. The ORM mapper should output these as classes closely mapped to the data source. To enable your repositories/controllers to be pluggable into various forms such as web services, web applications and other projects with little hassle there should be no UI attributes applied.

Automapper is great when you are targeting multiple implementations of your repository interfaces, as with DI containers. It is very useful when translating your domain objects to/from storage class objects.  Basically it reduces the need of translation classes.

At the MVC.Model area you may be required to create dups of the domain object classes that you utilize in the UI as models. As your project grows you will see the advantage of this especially if you are making use of various attributes for validation, display, localization, etc. Tools like Automapper greatly increase productivity when you have classes with very close naming conventions.

You will also see a gain in productivity if you use a mapper in your Mvc.Controller classes to translate from data/controller to MVC.Models.

The key is to be consistent with the property names in your classes across application boundaries.

Answer (score 1):

This is currently matter of discussion.  [Jimmy Bogard](http://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2009/06/30/how-we-do-mvc-view-models/) sugestion is to use Automapper to only map domain models into view models.  If you want too unflatte back view models to domain models I suggest you to give a try to [Value Injecter](http://valueinjecter.codeplex.com/)